# Android filtering logcat unless run as superuser

Tags: android, logging, adb, logcat

I can't figure out what is going on. I am using ANdroid Studio 1.6 and I have made sure I am set to "Verbose" and I have deleted all of my filters. However when I run an application on my device, I see almost no messages. Not absolutely nothing, but maybe a dozen I/D/E level messages from dalvik and the android runtime. NOthing from my application and certainly not enough messages that I would expect from a daily driver device that has a number of apps on it with online services.

I am so confused, I've looked in every corner of the Android Studio configuration and I can't see where I might be missing something. I KNOW that it is suppressing messages because when I use my on-device logcat reader, I see everything just as expected, and it's dramatically different from what AndroidStudio is showing.

Edit: going to terminal emulator on the device and starting log cat had the same effect (messages being hidden) so this must be on the device somewhere.

Tried logcat -c and checked ANDROID_LOG TAGS

Edit2: from terminal emulator if I just type log cat then I have the aforementioned problem. If I type su logcat however then I see everything. Why would I need superuser to view the full logcat?? How would I even instruct ddms to request superuser?

Comment: There may be going on here than I originally thought. If I close android studio and do a terminal ADB session, I see a very suppressed log output. However I still see full messages from the log reader application I have. Is there some device level setting that controls what goes out of ADB through usb!?

Comment: SInce Studio is pre-release preview software and certainly not  daily driver, you should check with an alternative IDE, e.g. IntelliJ, and log a bug if it's Studio specific.

Comment: I'm convinced now that it's something on the device because if I look at logcat through terminal emu I'm getting the same results. I guess the app I was using to read logs overrides this somewhere. After reading around I'm wondering if some app I installed has placed some overreaching log silencer in proguard